# What is gatling's "inferHtmlResources" resource limits?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

## The Issue

Gatling script is currently stopping at 14 requests and doesn't continue iterating in the scenario. Can't understand why...

## The Background // The Setup

I had a set of pages that was being tested successfully in Gatling until I had the need to move the static assets into a new subdomain.

On a first stage and to evaluate the capacity of the new servers, the first step on doing that move was done via redirects (301) to the new domain - let's call it assets.testdomain.com (and yes we're aware this isn't the ideal approach - this was done to allow for work to proceed without backend code changes).

After the above mentioned changes were applied, **most of our pages stopped iterating on the load test and would stop at 14 requests (HTML request + 13 css, js and image assets)**.

We've noticed that Gatling is following the redirects as expected and that iff the page has a small amount of assets in it, no issues were observed (scenario runs as intended).

## The Gatling Script

Here's the overall outline of my script:

```
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("https://www.testdomain.com")
    .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(), WhiteList("https://.*.testdomain.com.*."))
    .acceptHeader("image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.9")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36")

  val SamplePage_0 = Map(
    "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

  val test_duration = 4 minute
  val pacing = 0 second
  val think_time = 10 second

  val SamplePage = scenario("SamplePage")

    .during(test_duration) {
      pause(pacing)
        .repeat(28) {
          pause(think_time)
            .exec(flushHttpCache)
            .group("SamplePage") {
              exec(http("request_0")
                .get("/samplepage")
                .headers(SamplePage_0))
            }
        }
    }

  setUp(
    SamplePage.inject(rampUsers(1) over (1 minute)),
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue, fixed in Gatling 3: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3449

Comment: Had been doing a lot of searching but didn't run into that issue. Guess it was my bad. Thanks for sharing (accepted as Answer)